# Python script replaces string only once and then copies everything

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, random

```
from string import ascii_letters, ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits
from random import choice

Pattern = input("Enter your Pattern: ")
s = Pattern

pattern_dict = {
        '/X': ascii_letters,
        '/L': ascii_lowercase,
        '/U': ascii_uppercase,
        '/0': digits
    }

for i in range(RepeatThisManyTimes):
    for pattern, replacement in pattern_dict.items():
        while pattern in s:
            s = s.replace(pattern, choice(replacement), 1
```

When I run print(s), it only replaces the input once and then it copies everything. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your replace code and explain what went wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed that part. Now I have a new problem. I edited the post so you can exactly see what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea using lowercase letters, uppercase letters and digits from the `string` module for convenience:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

s = 'ABC-/U-/L-/0'

pattern_dict = {
    '/L': ascii_lowercase,
    '/U': ascii_uppercase,
    '/0': digits
}

for pattern, replacement in pattern_dict.items():
    while pattern in s:
        s = s.replace(pattern, choice(replacement), 1)
```

The idea is to iterate over the pair of patterns to find (`\L`, `\U`, `\0`) and their respective pool of possible values to replace (`ascii_lowercase`, `ascii_uppercase`, `digits`) in the dictionary. Then, while a given pattern appears in the string, we replace one of its occurrences with a value taken at random from the replacement pool.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for helping me. I tried it and it works. Now I am facing another problem though. I tried putting that inside a for loop so it repeats a certain amount of times, the problem now is that it is always the same text. It chooses random strings only once and then it just prints the exact same thing. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'd have to look at your code to see what could be wrong. Make sure to call `choice` on every iteration, instead of only once (otherwise you make a random choice a single time and always use that same choice). Also check if you're not overwriting any important variables in the process.

Comment: Once you run the loop for the first time, `s` has been modified, so it does not have any pattern `/L`, `/U` or `/0` left in it, which is why you don't see any changes afterwards. You need to "refresh" `s` with each iteration of your `for i in range(RepeatThisManyTimes)` loop. Try putting the line `s = Pattern` inside this loop.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed everything. Just because you explained it so well, I now have an Idea that can help me fix problems myself. I should look at the code and understand what exactly happens. Thanks a lot again.